# OSX - signing identity missing private key

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, keychain

After I accidently deleted my local keychain... it seems I have encountered some problems. (This is my first Mac.)

In Xcode - Preferences - Accounts it has an error. If I click "View details" for my developer account, it list one signing identity called "iOS Development". However, its status is missing private key. (If I try to add one for distribution, it also pops up saying I already have one.)

As I already redownloaded both my distribution and development certificate from my developer profile and put them into my local keychain... I guess this means they somehow were not enough? Is there any other place on my Mac where I can (be lucky and) find my private key? certificate? ...

Or will I need to revoke my certificates in my developer profile? Download new certificate and create new provision profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key is used for signing the code and the certificate is used for verifying the code. Since the private key is only stored in your keychain and you deleted it.

The only way to recover from it is to create a new developer certificate and generate a new Developer Provisioning Profile for your app.